# Command Line looking wrong

Tags: command, rvm, line

My command line looks like this:

```
|system||system|ruby 2.0.0p645 (system) User_name-MacBook-Air in ~
```

Can someone tell me how to edit this down to:

```
User_name-MacBook-Air in
```

I have a feeling it has to do with a recent RVM issue I was having, but any help on cutting down

```
|system||system|ruby 2.0.0p645 (system)
```

Comment: what happens if you do `cd /`?

Comment: i just imploded rvm and one of the systems is done now

Comment: |system|ruby 2.0.0p645 (system) User_name-MacBook-Air in ~